# skipping validations in rails, how to define each instance of the class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to add the skip validation methods to my sessions controller but i am unsure what to define omniauth as and basic login as. Ie they are both from class User but in sessions controller do I put

```
  def create
   user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])   
 **user.from_omniauth.skip_name_validation = true**
   etc etc
```

Then also want to add validate for the methods in the model as put in bold and add that to my sessions controller so both instances of each login are able to be bypassed.

My sessions controller

```
  def create
   user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

  unless user.present?
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      # Create an error message.
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end    
  else        
    log_in user
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

My model.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },
**unless: :skip_name_validation**
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                  **unless: :skip_email_validation**
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil:true,
**unless: :skip_password_validation**

 **attr_accessor :skip_name_validation, :skip_email_validation, :skip_password_validation**

 **attr_accessor :skip_User, :skip_self**

**validate :User, unless: :skip_User**
**validate :self, unless: :skip_self**

  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Was the information given by me  was helpful?

Comment: helpful, but not right as far as when I tired it out.

Comment: anyone, have any idea on this?

Comment: are you using devise?

Comment: I am only following a tutorial https://richonrails.com/articles/facebook-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails and following the Michael Hartl tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book but as I am finding out I am having mixed results.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
       attr_accessor :password_confirmation, :skip_password_validation 
       validates :password, :presence => true ,unless: :skip_password_validation
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => ->{ password.present? },unless: :skip_password_validation

      def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                      BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end

      def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid = auth.uid
          user.name = auth.info.name
          user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
          user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
          user.save!
        end
      end
    end


    def create
       user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
      #######try this #####
     user.skip_password_validation = true
 ####or try this ####
    user.from_omniauth.skip_name_validation = true

      unless user.present?
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
         if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
          log_in user
          redirect_to user
          # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
        else
          # Create an error message.
          flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
          render 'new'
        end    
      else        
        log_in user
        redirect_to user
      end
    end
```

Comment: that code is still saying the email cant be blank, password cant be blank.. password cant be blank should atleast be eliminated